# HTML hyperlink to NSAttributedString did not style

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nsattributedstring

I am attempting to create NSAttributedString from given HTML string, with paragraph and hyperlink. Everything is fine, except styling hyperlink. 
My code to style looks like:

```
func htmlAttributed() -> NSAttributedString? {
    do {
        let htmlCSSString = "<style>" +
            "* {" +
                "font-size: 12px !important;" +
                "color: #9D9B98 !important;" +
            "}" +
            "p" +
            "{" +
                "font-size: 12px !important;" +
                "color: #9D9B98 !important;" +
                "font-family: Helvetica !important;" +
            "}" +
            "a" +
            "{" +
                "font-size: 12px !important;" +
                "color: hotpink !important;" +
                "font-family: Helvetica !important;" +
            "}" +
            "a:link" +
            "{" +
            "text-decoration: none !important;" +
            "color: hotpink !important;" +
            "}" +
            "a:visited" +
            "{" +
            "text-decoration: none !important;" +
            "}" +
            "</style> \(self)"

        guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
            return nil
        }

        return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                      options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                      documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print("error: ", error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

and it giving great result when I open it in website. But translation to NSAttributedString works only for p mark, not for hyperlink.

For testing I use this part of code

```
<p>This is not a link <b><a class='test' href='test' target='_blank'>This is a link</a></b></p>
```

On w3c playground I have:
[image]

On iPhone I've got:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `UILabel`, try using `UITextView` instead and change link colors using `linkTextAttributes`. This way your links will also be tappable.

```
textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemPink]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, UITextView is not possible in this case.

Comment: I couldn't find a proper solution for UILabel. This seems to be the way NSAttributedString treats with links.